# Execute python commands passed as strings in command line using python -c

Tags: python

Is it possible to  execute python commands passed as strings using python -c? can someone give an example.

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: actually, I was looking for how to use python -c "<input code>" format.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For *a single string* you can use `python -c`. But for *strings* as the question asks, you must pass them to stdin:

```
$ python << EOF
> import sys
> print sys.version
> EOF
2.7.3 (default, Apr 13 2012, 20:16:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)]
```

Comment: I found the answer. just copy paste this on the terminal.
python -c "import sys; x = 'hello world'; print x;"

Comment: That's *a* string. If you want *strings* then you need to feed them to stdin.

Answer (score 73):

You can use `-c` to get Python to execute a string. For example:

`python3 -c "print(5)"`

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to use escape characters (e.g. `\n`). So, if you need them, use a pipe from `echo -e` or `printf` instead. For example:

`$ printf "import sys\nprint(sys.path)" | python3`

Comment: `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` is simpler.

Comment: @mattmc3 You can't end a block (where indentation would decrease) with a semicolon. So it's more limited; you can't, for example, create a function and then actually call it, or use an if-else, or even an if followed by unconditional code. But (where possible) that is simpler.