# How do you execute python without providing a file name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am relatively new to python, so I was wondering if I could call upon python to read a string (or the code it needs to execute) from outside the interactive python shell, similar to how exec() works when within Python.
Basically, I want to know if there is any method to have python read code from the command line or otherwise rather than having to save that code within a 'file.py' or another similar file. 
I want to avoid running this: `python file.py` as I hope to avoid needing a filename.
I was looking around for a solution and found [Execute python commands passed as strings in command line using python -c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768584/execute-python-commands-passed-as-strings-in-command-line-using-python-c) and [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument). The first answer seems to be what I might want, but I lack in the knowledge department of how to pass the string into stdin, so I would be grateful if someone could better explain that method if it is the correct answer. The second link was what I found when looking up about stdin, and looked promising, but upon execution I realized that, from my understanding, I still need some sort of file name for subprocess. 
I was planning to use this in order to be used in Jupyter Notebook, or any similar program so when I run one data cell, it is able to be executed in Python or return the error message, but to first do that I have to find out how to reference the language I want without needing a file name. Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: You can pipe your code into the interpreter.

Comment: @Klaus D. Can you elaborate? I have tried piping using the following code: `def exec_py(code):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", 'f'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    return_code = proc.wait()
    proc.stdin.write('code')
    out = proc.stdout.read()
    err = proc.stderr.read()
    if (err):
        return(err.decode("utf-8"))
    else:
        return(out.decode("utf-8"))` where code would be given by running an individual cell in Jupyter, but once again it requires a file named 'f' that I cannot provide.

Comment: Just... don't provide a file name? Run `python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit unclear exactly what you want to to with this but here is hello world using the command option (-c) from the command line without piping it in. This just runs the string passed as if it was in the python interpreter or in a script.

```
python -c "print('hello world')"
```

If you really want to run code from stdin you could use something like this:

```
echo "for i in range(100):\n\tprint(i)" | python -c "import sys;print('hello world');exec(''.join([item for item in sys.stdin]))"
```

There is more on how to use the command line tool in the man page or in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html).

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I was looking for an answer that could provide more than one string. I found that method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768584/execute-python-commands-passed-as-strings-in-command-line-using-python-c but as the first response stated, it cannot print more than one string. `python -c "x = 'hello', print(x)"` doesn't seem to work. Do you know how to pass python code into stdin, as apparently that is the answer but I am unfamiliar with it

Comment: that won't work but python -c "x = 'hello';print(x)" does

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
python -c "my_var = 'my name is john';print(my_var)"
```

**Note that**

1) using ; you seperate the commands.

2) you need to use " " and inside to type the commands.